# Reading from a file: find the new line

Tags: python, file, file-io

I am trying to read a text file using python. The code is given below:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            val=line.split()
```

It simply reads from a text file and ensures that it reads all the lines at once. I want to change its implementation. Suppose that it is in a function and I have an already opened file, how do I ensure that I **read a new line every time I call the function**?

I have read about the `seek` function, can I use it to seek to a new line every time the function is called?

Comment: How about calling `f.readline()` and passing the file `f` as a parameter to the function?

Comment: @SergioA. I have 2 conditions, first when I need to call the function without the descriptor and another where I need it with the descriptor so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator, like this

```
def get_next_line(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip()
```

and you can get the next line, like this

```
for line in get_next_line("Input.txt"):
    print line
```

But you want to get the next lines, not in a loop then you can explicitly use `next` function, like this

```
my_file = get_next_line("Input.txt")
print next(my_file)
print next(my_file)
```